# React Native Horizontal ListView Resets Scroll View contentOffset on update

Tags: listview, react-native, scrollview

I've a horizontal ListView. When the dataSource is updated, hence the ListView,  it scrolls with contentOffset `{0,0}`, no matter what the current contentOffset is. Here is the snippet of view:

```
<ListView
      horizontal
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections({
        section1: this.state.products,
      })}
      renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
    />
```

I've tried `onScroll={this.handleScroll.bind(this)}` and updating contentOffset in global state, but the changes don't reflect even when ListView is update with `contentOffset={this.state.contentOffset}`.